# Which CPU cooler should I buy?

Tags: cooling

I found these 4 coolers for the same price, but I don't know which should I buy.

I favor performance and temperature. the size/looks doesn't really matter, if it fits in the chassis I'm happy (780T Full Tower PC Case).

I don't plan to overclock anything.

CPU cooler for Intel I7 6700k + Z170 deluxe + single GTX 980ti build.

Would be nice to have a silent build, but it's not that big deal. A cooler that doesn't need maintenance is a huge plus (I guess closed water cooler and vapor chamber don't need maintenance...)

- Cooler Master V8 GTS
- Thermalright Silver Arrow IB-E Extreme
- Corsair Hydro Series H100i
- Phanteks PH-TC14PE 140mm UFB

If there is a better cooler suited for me under 100$ I will be interested to know...

I know this question is somewhat subjective, but I can't find the answer online, I only see different opinions everywhere...

Comment: Please provide more details. What workload are you doing? Are you planning to overclock?

Comment: @Peter I will not overclock anything. I'll use this computer to work with game design (Graphics to Programming, 3D and 2D) and play AAA games. Example of programs I'll use: Blender, Maya, Unity 3D, Photoshop, Unreal Engine 4. Games: Far cry 4, Gta 5. I'll use a single 1080p monitor. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered going Haswell-E (5820K) instead? The 2 extra cores may be more helpful than the slightly higher single thread performance on the 6700K, and it's actually cheaper (unless you live near microcenter, in which case the price is even), even including the higher cost for a X99 motherboard, which you can use to get more RAM or a larger SSD.

Comment: There is no such thing as an answer for your question, there are only opinions. If you don't plan to OC, then even box cooler will suffice. Why not try the box cooler first and then find out if it has any disadvantages you want to get rid of? There is no point in getting 0dB CPU cooler when your GTX will crank up to 11.

Comment: If you don't plan on overclocking, any CPU cooler will do that supports the LGA 115x socket. Since the 6700k runs very cool, you don't need a fancy cooler, a cheap one will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all these 4 coolers are the same price, I would recommend the H100i. It is a very powerful closed loop CPU cooler (I have done some serious overclock with this cooler). Since you got a overclockable CPU, if you want to overclock in the future you can do that with this cooler no problem. The new Skylake CPUs have a thinner PCB, so heavy CPU coolers can actually bend the chip (not a good thing). Since all the other choices are really heavy tower coolers, the H100i can prevent the CPU from bending.